# How to send raw SOAP request in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, soap

I need to send a raw SOAP request to server.
My request looks like

```
POST http://10.76.243.43:8080/registry/services/xds-iti18 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 6383
Host: 10.76.243.43:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" xmlns:urn2="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:AdhocQueryRequest id="?" comment="?" federated="false" federation="?" startIndex="0" maxResults="-1">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn1:RequestSlotList>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <urn2:Slot name="?" slotType="?">
               <urn2:ValueList>
                  <urn2:Value>?</urn2:Value>
               </urn2:ValueList>
            </urn2:Slot>
         </urn1:RequestSlotList>
         <urn:ResponseOption returnType="RegistryObject" returnComposedObjects="false"/>
         <urn2:AdhocQuery id="?" home="?" lid="?" objectType="?" status="?">
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <urn2:Slot name="?" slotType="?">
               <urn2:ValueList>
                  <urn2:Value>?</urn2:Value>
               </urn2:ValueList>
            </urn2:Slot>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <urn2:Name>
               <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
            </urn2:Name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <urn2:Description>
               <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
            </urn2:Description>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <urn2:VersionInfo versionName="1.1" comment="?"/>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <urn2:Classification id="?" home="?" lid="?" objectType="?" status="?" classificationScheme="?" classifiedObject="?" classificationNode="?" nodeRepresentation="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn2:Slot name="?" slotType="?">
                  <urn2:ValueList>
                     <urn2:Value>?</urn2:Value>
                  </urn2:ValueList>
               </urn2:Slot>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn2:Name>
                  <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
               </urn2:Name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn2:Description>
                  <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
               </urn2:Description>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn2:VersionInfo versionName="1.1" comment="?"/>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn2:Classification/>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn2:ExternalIdentifier id="?" home="?" lid="?" objectType="?" status="?" registryObject="?" identificationScheme="?" value="?">
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <urn2:Slot name="?" slotType="?">
                     <urn2:ValueList>
                        <urn2:Value>?</urn2:Value>
                     </urn2:ValueList>
                  </urn2:Slot>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <urn2:Name>
                     <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
                  </urn2:Name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <urn2:Description>
                     <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
                  </urn2:Description>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <urn2:VersionInfo versionName="1.1" comment="?"/>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <urn2:Classification/>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <urn2:ExternalIdentifier/>
               </urn2:ExternalIdentifier>
            </urn2:Classification>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <urn2:ExternalIdentifier id="?" home="?" lid="?" objectType="?" status="?" registryObject="?" identificationScheme="?" value="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn2:Slot name="?" slotType="?">
                  <urn2:ValueList>
                     <urn2:Value>?</urn2:Value>
                  </urn2:ValueList>
               </urn2:Slot>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn2:Name>
                  <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
               </urn2:Name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn2:Description>
                  <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
               </urn2:Description>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn2:VersionInfo versionName="1.1" comment="?"/>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn2:Classification id="?" home="?" lid="?" objectType="?" status="?" classificationScheme="?" classifiedObject="?" classificationNode="?" nodeRepresentation="?">
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <urn2:Slot name="?" slotType="?">
                     <urn2:ValueList>
                        <urn2:Value>?</urn2:Value>
                     </urn2:ValueList>
                  </urn2:Slot>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <urn2:Name>
                     <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
                  </urn2:Name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <urn2:Description>
                     <urn2:LocalizedString xml:lang="en-US" charset="UTF-8" value="?"/>
                  </urn2:Description>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <urn2:VersionInfo versionName="1.1" comment="?"/>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <urn2:Classification/>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <urn2:ExternalIdentifier/>
               </urn2:Classification>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn2:ExternalIdentifier/>
            </urn2:ExternalIdentifier>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <urn2:QueryExpression queryLanguage="?">
               e
               <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
               gero
            </urn2:QueryExpression>
         </urn2:AdhocQuery>
      </urn:AdhocQueryRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It is standard raw request generated by SOAP UI (using wsdl of web service), so if I send it there I get HTTP code 200 and some normal response.
I want to send it using Java, so I do the following

```
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\timofb\\Documents\\testtest.txt"));//file with my raw request
String soapXml = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Socket socket = new Socket("10.76.243.43", 8080);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out.write(soapXml);
out.flush();
System.out.println("\n * Response");    
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

I get HTTP status 500 and SOAP message that Fault occurred while processing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer. This code worked for me

```
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\timofb\\Documents\\test.txt"));
    String soapXml = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory =
            SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    java.net.URL endpoint = new URL("http://" + ip + "/cs-repository/services/xds-iti41");
    SOAPConnection connection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded));
    AttachmentPart attachment = message.createAttachmentPart();
    attachment.setContent("sm_content", "text/plain");
    attachment.setContentId("1.9f910338bf0cac0e783bfdec7e53be9237684caa8f8f4e6d@apache.org");
    message.addAttachmentPart(attachment);
    SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.writeTo(out);
    String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
    return strMsg;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try like this: you need to replace the xmldata with yours:

```
   try {
        String xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Envelopey> your reuest</soapenv:Envelope>";
        String hostname = "10.76.243.43";
        int port = 8080;
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
        Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);

        //Send header
        String path = "registry/services/xds-iti18";
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        wr.write("POST "+path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        wr.write("Host: "+hostname+":"+port+"\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Length: "+ xmldata.length() + "\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
        wr.write("\r\n");            //Send data
        wr.write(xmldata);
        wr.flush();

        // Response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println("Response:"+line);
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! If you have trouble with InvalidSecurity then add wr.write("SOAPAction: <URI from your wsdl, this element:  wsaw:Action=... > \r\n");

Answer (score 1):

I know that It's a little bit late, but Unirest saved me a lot.

You should simply try something like:

```
        Unirest.setTimeouts(0, 0);
        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("YOUR URL OPERATION")
          .header("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml")
          .body("YOUR RAW FILE")
          .asString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of socket you can use java HttpURLConnection, Here you must have set SOAPAction header attribute properly in you case it is "AdhocQueryRequest" or you can cross check from your wsdl, below is tentative untested code.

```
    URL url = new URL(SOAPUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(xmlFile2Send);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Copy the SOAP file to the open connection.
    copy(fin,bout);
    fin.close();

    byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();

    // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
    httpConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length",
                                 String.valueOf( b.length ) );
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
      httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",SOAPAction);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);

    // Everything's set up; send the XML that was read in to b.
    OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    out.write( b );    
    out.close();

    // Read the response and write it to standard out.

    InputStreamReader isr =
        new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
```