# How to connect an SSL enabled asmx web service with android

Tags: android, web-services, ssl, android-ksoap2

i'm trying to connect an asmx web service which has SSL enabled certificate from symantec. The web service works fine in browser with green indication. But unable to connect the webservice with android using ksoap library. I have added the public key of certificate(.cer file) in the aseets folder and added it to the trustmanager.

Comment: I faced same issue some time back and finally I call the webservice using normal java HTTP Connection.

Comment: Yes, In background finally http url connection works ... see how to call soap webservice using http url connection.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286722/how-to-send-raw-soap-request-in-java/31287188#31287188

Comment: But using https is secured with SSL. http doesn't gives the secured path in between client and server.

Comment: Please use HttpsUrlConnection.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat let me try. Thank you.

Comment: Its works perfect right now. done minor changes in ksoap2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete solution for how to handle SSL over android and c# webservice by using ksoap.

1. customise your org.ksoap2.transport.org.ksoap2.transport class constructor like this

---

```
public HttpTransportSE(Certificate ca, String url) {
    super(ca, url);
}
```

2. change some codes in org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE class

```
public ServiceConnectionSE(Certificate ca, String url) throws IOException
{

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore;
    SSLContext context = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);


    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext


    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
}
```

---

3. And send your Certificate ca

---

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open("your_cert.cer"));
Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(ca, url);
```

---