# How to call a SOAP based API using java assume that request xml is already known to me

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am new to API calling. I have the following things with me..

1. I know the wsdl url
2. I know the request xml stored in my local system (xml we provide when we  call a API via SOAP UI)

Now how can I call the API easily via java and capture the response. In addition I need to provide credential(known to me) when accessing/calling the API

Could anyone please provide me the sample code for that.

My XML looks like that...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" mlns:eee="http://eee.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ehhm:createOrgUser>

<!--Optional:-->
<userData>
<!--Optional:-->
<userName>sharepointnew</userName>
<!--Optional:-->
<organizationId>609980298</organizationId>
<!--Optional:-->
<organizationAccountId>609980299</organizationAccountId>
<!--Optional:-->
<resellerId></resellerId>
<!--Optional:-->
<organizationAttribute>Education</organizationAttribute>
<!--Optional:-->
<primaryRoleName>Customer Super Admin</primaryRoleName>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<secondaryRoleName></secondaryRoleName>
<!--Optional:-->
<password>Independent12#</password>
<!--Optional:-->
<attributeList>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<attribute>
<!--Optional:-->
<key>FirstName</key>
<!--Optional:-->
<value>Morgan</value>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<!--Optional:-->
<key>LastName</key>
<!--Optional:-->
<value>Packards</value>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<!--Optional:-->
<key>ContactEmail</key>
<!--Optional:-->
<value>bmondal@ejuu.com</value>
</attribute>

</attributeList>
<!--Optional:-->
<storePwIn>true</storePwIn>
</userData>
</escm:createOrgUser>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I need to create connection and call the API using this XML.

Thank in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send raw SOAP request in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286722/how-to-send-raw-soap-request-in-java)

Comment: You could use JAX-WS RT...read [here](http://www.javadb.com/create-a-web-service-client-with-jax-ws/), this guide is very helpful